# for and while loop continues to loop even though it shouldn't C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio, loops

Not a duplicate of [C++ for loop continue to loop even though it shouldn't](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55063637/c-for-loop-continue-to-loop-even-though-it-shouldnt)

I found out that for loop continues even though the conditions are false. An example is here

```
int isSubstring(std::string s1, std::string s2)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < s2.size() - s1.size(); i++) {
        
    }
    return -1;
}
```

If I call it like `isSubtring("abcd", "a");` it should've returned -1 right? But it doesn't. In Visual Studio debugger I saw the value of `i` goes up forever.
But, if call this

```
for (int i = 0; i < -3; i++) {
        std::cout << "\ni=" << i;
    }
```

It behaves as intended. This also applies for while loop. My question is, why is that?

Edit: removed unnecessary code

Comment: [Beware](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5416414/signed-unsigned-comparisons) of mixing signed and unsigned types. `size()` returns a value of unsigned type. `a.size() - b.size() >= 0` is **always** true.

Comment: `cout << s2.size() - s1.size() << endl;` returns a large number. You should fix your types.

Comment: A `std::string`'s  `size()` member returns an unsigned type, and subtracting unsigned values gives an unsigned value.   The condition in your code of `i < s2.size() - s1.size()` will never end if `s1.size() > s2.size()`, since `s2.size() - s1.size()` will give a large positive value.  For example, if `s2.size()` is zero and `s1.size()` is `1`, the `s2.size() - s1.size()` will give typically give a value equal to `std::numeric_limits<std::size_t>::max()`   (assuming that the return type of `size()` is `std::size_t`, which is common in practice, albeit not guaranteed).

Comment: Please compile your program with `-Wall` (all warnings enabled), fix those warnings and _then_ see if the problem still exists.

Comment: Thamk you @Evg . Should I do this? `i < (int)s2.size() - (int)s1.size()`

Comment: @Ryazack - Only if you want undefined behaviour if `s2.size()` or `s1.size()` are larger than can be stored in an `int`.

Comment: @Ryazack, `std:ptrdiff_t` would be a better choice.